# How can I create condition "if there is no event belonging to the selected category" in Symfony twig?

Tags: symfony, if-statement

I'd like to show an element if there is no event belonging to the category. Before landing on list of events user has selected a category previously in a search form.

How can I write a condition saying 'if there is no event belonging to the selected category' ?

I tried this but I ended up with this error :

```
Key "category" for array with keys "0" does not exist.
```

My code on twig :

```
{% if events.category.id != category.id %}

    <a href="#">Comment participer ?</a>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error text it seems that your `events` variable is an array of objects, so you can't use `.category.id` in a condition without a loop. You need a loop to determine if the event is set with the category you want in the array, if not, display your message

```
{% set event_isset = false %}
{% for event in events %}
    {% if event.category.id == category.id %}
        {% set event_isset = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if not event_isset %}
    <a href="#">Comment participer ?</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your events is an array of objects/arrays each of which has key `category` then this condition should work:

```
{% if events|filter(e => e.category == category.id)|length == 0 %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Docs https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html